# Hue Install From Tarball Failure Django Error?

Tags: django, hadoop, hue

After running `PREFIX=/home/hue make install`

**Towards the end** of my hue install via tarball, I get the following error. I'm not sure what is happening. I have the prerequisites installed as well. [Using this guide](https://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-2.0.1/manual.html)

Command that is failing: `/home/hue/hue/build/env/bin/hue makemigrations --noinput`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hue/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('desktop', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
  File "/home/hue/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 216, in entry
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/hue/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/settings.py", line 271, in <module>
    conf.initialize(_desktop_conf_modules, _config_dir)
  File "/home/hue/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/conf.py", line 598, in initialize
    conf_data = load_confs(_configs_from_dir(config_dir))
  File "/home/hue/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/conf.py", line 530, in load_confs
    for in_conf in conf_source:
  File "/home/hue/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/conf.py", line 511, in _configs_from_dir
    conf = ConfigObj(os.path.join(conf_dir, filename))
  File "/home/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py2.7.egg/configobj.py", line 1229, in __init__
    self._load(infile, configspec)
  File "/home/hue/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py2.7.egg/configobj.py", line 1318, in _load
    raise error
configobj.ConfigObjError: Parsing failed with several errors.
First error at line 1046.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this. So the issue stemmed from modifying the `hue.ini` file before running the install. Rolling back to the original `hue.ini` resolved the issue. I must have had a typo in the modified version, thus causing the parse error above.

Tarball File location:

```
hue/desktop/conf/hue.ini
```